# Fetching a specific div text on another local file and store it in a variable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm already using `$("#test").load("/content/extra.html #test");` to fetch the specific div id on another local html file and show that on the main user window, it works like a charm.

But now I need to *store this specific div id text data on a variable*...

### Already tried

Using $.get:

`$.get( "/conent/extra.html #test", function( textdata ) { alert( textdata ); });`

This is showing the whole page not only the #test div

Making variables and using load:

`var test = $("#test"); var textdata;`

`test.load("/content/extra.html #test"); textdata = test;`

This is showing the whole thing again xD

### Conclusion

Shall I somehow use $.get and cut the specific div id I'm looking for which I don't know how and seems very painful to me, or there's a better approach on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial selector doesn't have to be an existing element on the page, it can be a newly created in-memory element.  For example:

```
let newElement = $("<div/>")
newElement.load("/content/extra.html #test");
```

Now `newElement` will itself be a `<div>` element, filled with the specified content from the call to `.load()`.  (Note of course the async nature of the operation, so it won't be *immediately* available.)  You can use it like any other jQuery object, getting its `.html()` or `.text()` as needed, etc:

```
let newText = newElement.text();
```

If at some later point you want to append it to the DOM, you can:

```
$("#someOtherElement").append(newElement);
```

Comment: Holy yeas! thank you soo much kind sir :D the .text() is the key, thanks for your explanation thank you